# Conditional merge of other multiple Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I have four pandas DataFrames (`A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`). `A` has a series of timestamps and a single column which refers to one of the other DataFrames:

```
A

Timestamp    Source
-----------  ------
2012-4-3     B
2013-12-20   C
2012-3-5     C
2014-12-7    D
2012-7-10    B
...
```

The other DataFrames hold more data:

```
B

Timestamp   Foo  Bar
----------- ---- ----
2012-1-1    1.5  1.3
2012-1-2    2.3  5.6
2012-1-3    3.4  3.3
...
2014-3-31   0.8  2.1

C

Timestamp   Foo  Bar
----------- ---- ----
2012-1-1    9.2  5.6
2012-1-2    4.8  7.6
2012-1-3    2.7  6.4
...
2014-3-31   7.0  6.5

D

Timestamp   Foo  Bar
----------- ---- ----
2012-1-1    6.8  4.2
2012-1-2    4.2  9.3
2012-1-3    5.5  0.7
...
2014-3-31   6.3  2.0
```

I want to construct a single DataFrame from `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` that has three columns (`Timestamp`, `Foo`, and `Bar`) where the values of `Foo` and `Bar` come from the corresponding `Timestamp` in the DataFrame listed as the `Source` in `A`.

Not all Timestamps in `A` appear in the other three DataFrames, in which case, I'd like the values of `Foo` and `Bar` to be `np.nan`. Not all timestamps in `B`, `C`, and `D` appear in `A`, and simply won't appear in the final DataFrame.

My current approach is to loop through each row in A and return the values from the corresponding `Source` DataFrame:

```
srcs = {'B': B, 'C': C, 'D': D}
A['Foo'] = np.nan
A['Bar'] = np.nan

for i in range(len(A)):
    ts = A.iloc[i].Timestamp
    src = A.iloc[i].Source
    A.iloc[i].Foo = srcs[src][srcs[src].Timestamp == ts].Foo
    A.iloc[i].Bar = srcs[src][srcs[src].Timestamp == ts].Bar
```

There has to be a more efficient, more Pandithic(?) way to perform this action?

Comment: Hmm, one method would be to add a Source column to each df with B, C, D set to B,C,D respectively and then merge all of them on TimeStamp and Source, not sure how messy it would be though

Comment: Wouldn't this lead to a df with 6 separate columns (e.g., 'Foo_x', 'Bar_x', 'Foo_y', 'Bar_y', 'Foo', 'Bar')? How would I combine them into two columns ('Foo', and 'Bar') based on the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could use a multi-index to do this.  Your index would be consist of the Timestamp and Source.  You can so this with the `set_index` method on a DataFrame.

Here is some code to create some fake DataFrames, each with the MultiIndex.

```
# Imports for creating fake data
from random import random
from random import choice

# Setup the sample data
A = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp':range(20), 'Source':[choice(others) for i in range(20)]})
# Create the MultiIndex on A
A.set_index(['TimeStamp', 'Source'], inplace=True)
A['Bar'] = [np.nan] * len(A)
A['Foo'] = [np.nan] * len(A)

B = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp':range(5), 
                  'Foo':[random()*5+5 for i in range(5)], 
                  'Bar':[random()*5+5 for i in range(5)]})
C = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp':range(5,10), 
                  'Foo':[random()*5+5 for i in range(5)], 
                  'Bar':[random()*5+5 for i in range(5)]})
D = pd.DataFrame({'TimeStamp':range(10,15), 
                  'Foo':[random()*5+5 for i in range(5)], 
                  'Bar':[random()*5+5 for i in range(5)]})

sources = {'B':B, 'C':C, 'D':D}

# create the MultiIndex on the Source data sets
for s, df in sources.items():
    df['Source'] = [s]*len(df)
    df.set_index(['TimeStamp', 'Source'], inplace=True)
```

Now you can index the Source data sets (B, C, and D) using the index on A.

```
for s, df in sources.items():    

    temp = df.loc[A.index]  # the source data set indexed by A's index
                            # this will contain NaN's where df does not
                            # have corresponding index entries
    temp.dropna(inplace=True) # dropping the NaN values leaves you with 
                             # only the values in df matching the index in A
    if len(temp) > 0:
        A.loc[temp.index] = temp  # now assign the data to A

print(A)
```

The result looks like:

```
                       Bar       Foo
TimeStamp Source                    
0         D            NaN       NaN
1         C            NaN       NaN
2         D            NaN       NaN
3         B       7.927154  8.581380
4         B       7.638422  5.970348
5         D            NaN       NaN
6         C       6.938001  6.417248
7         B            NaN       NaN
8         C       5.131940  9.144621
9         B            NaN       NaN
10        D       9.186963  5.991877
11        D       8.070543  7.735040
12        C            NaN       NaN
13        B            NaN       NaN
14        C            NaN       NaN
15        D            NaN       NaN
16        C            NaN       NaN
17        C            NaN       NaN
18        C            NaN       NaN
19        B            NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

## Setup

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

texta = """Timestamp    Source
2012-4-3     B
2012-4-2     B
2013-12-20   C
2012-3-5     C
2014-12-7    D
2012-7-10    B"""

A = pd.read_csv(StringIO(texta), delim_whitespace=1, parse_dates=[0])

textb = """Timestamp   Foo  Bar
2012-1-1    1.5  1.3
2012-4-3    3.1  4.1
2012-1-2    2.3  5.6
2012-1-3    3.4  3.3
2014-3-31   0.8  2.1"""

B = pd.read_csv(StringIO(textb), delim_whitespace=1, parse_dates=[0])

textc = """Timestamp   Foo  Bar
2012-1-1    9.2  5.6
2012-3-5    4.8  7.6
2012-1-2    4.8  7.6
2012-1-3    2.7  6.4
2014-3-31   7.0  6.5"""

C = pd.read_csv(StringIO(textc), delim_whitespace=1, parse_dates=[0])

textd = """Timestamp   Foo  Bar
2012-1-1    6.8  4.2
2012-1-2    4.2  9.3
2012-1-3    5.5  0.7
2014-3-31   6.3  2.0"""

D = pd.read_csv(StringIO(textd), delim_whitespace=1, parse_dates=[0])
```

Then I combine with `pd.concat` just `B` `C` and `D`

```
bdf = pd.concat([B, C, D], keys=['B', 'C', 'D'])
bdf.reset_index(level=1, inplace=1, drop=1)
bdf.index.name = 'Source'
bdf.reset_index(inplace=1)

print bdf
```

It looks like this:

```
   Source  Timestamp  Foo  Bar
0       B 2012-01-01  1.5  1.3
1       B 2012-04-03  3.1  4.1
2       B 2012-01-02  2.3  5.6
3       B 2012-01-03  3.4  3.3
4       B 2014-03-31  0.8  2.1
5       C 2012-01-01  9.2  5.6
6       C 2012-03-05  4.8  7.6
7       C 2012-01-02  4.8  7.6
8       C 2012-01-03  2.7  6.4
9       C 2014-03-31  7.0  6.5
10      D 2012-01-01  6.8  4.2
11      D 2012-01-02  4.2  9.3
12      D 2012-01-03  5.5  0.7
13      D 2014-03-31  6.3  2.0
```

## Finally

a simple merge

```
A.merge(bdf, how='left')
```

Looks like:

```
   Timestamp Source  Foo  Bar
0 2012-04-03      B  3.1  4.1
1 2012-04-02      B  NaN  NaN
2 2013-12-20      C  NaN  NaN
3 2012-03-05      C  4.8  7.6
4 2014-12-07      D  NaN  NaN
5 2012-07-10      B  NaN  NaN
```